# Combobox component for Swift, select an element by default

Tags: swift

I'm using this component:
https://github.com/Darkseal/DownPicker

```
let persons = ["Architect", "Designer", "Chef", "Doctor"]
self.personDownPicker = DownPicker(textField: self.personTextField, withData:persons)
```

And it's displaying the data correctly, but, how I can have an option selected by default?

Comment: You can just set the text field's text, can't you?

Comment: I am amazed you need a pod for such a simple functionality...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking into the source code, the `DownPicker` instance has a `selectedIndex` property. Set it to the index of the selected item.